# Using Powercfg to remove Hibernation file does not work , even though I am the Administrator

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

On a windows 7 install to a SSD drive the hiberfil.sys file was created, I want to remove it. I not only have administration rights on the computer, I am the one administrator, having taken over the default admin.

As you can see in the **CMD** (top left), when putting in the command `powercfg -H Off` , it just says `Invalid Parameters - - try "/?" for help`,  so I tried different caps/non-caps variations. See **Administator** there in the title.

[image]

**Deleting:** In the requester there (bottom left) You can see I attempted to delete the file, which tossed up `This action cannot be completed because the file is open in another program`

**Settings:** In the power options (right) you can see hibernation was turned off, and the computer had since been booted.

**Explorer:** In the explorer window (bottom) you can see the existance of the hiberfil.sys System file, as it resides on the root of the C: disk which is a partition of the SSD.

Why does the powercfg -H Off function not work to remove the hibernation file, when i am the administrator?

Comment: You could try the registry method explained in this link: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/819-hibernate-enable-disable.html (obviously at your own risk)

Comment: Does `powercfg /h off` work?

Comment: @rik  Yes , Well that is odd because the help file shows -H , right now both methods are working. I had to RunAs the admin in this situation before any of them would, so if you answer , be sure to add RunAs to the answer as a possible need.

Comment: Added my answer. I take it the "RunAs" command is the same as Right-click/Run as administrator to run an elevated command prompt.

Comment: "In the power options (right) you can see hibernation was turned off, and the computer had since been booted." - That doesn't tell you that "hibernation is turned off". That simply tells you that the computer is not set to automatically hibernate after a period of inactivity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes `powercfg` needs a `-` and sometimes a `/` at the beginning of a parameter.

This [Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824902.aspx) for Windows 8 states a `/` and another older [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940(v=ws.10).aspx) a `-`. (Which has worked since Windows XP).

For me (Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit) both variations work. In the [second article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940(v=ws.10).aspx) one user stated (with the same configuration) he had trouble with the `-` where `/` worked. So the reason is still a mystery.

To run the command you can click start, type cmd, and right-click `cmd.exe` on the top and choose `run as administrator` (or you won't have elevated rights to perform the command).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
powercfg -hibernate off
```

This is how I solved it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was getting "Invalid Parameters" for `powercfg /devicequery wake_armed` on Windows 8.1. After looking at the options by typing `powercfg /? devicequery`, I copied the example which uses all caps for all except the query flag:

`POWERCFG /DEVICEQUERY wake_armed`

That worked. So maybe `POWERCFG /HIBERNATE off` would work in your case.